# How to take advantage of VirtualBox paravirtualization in an Ubuntu guest?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, performance, kvm-virtualization

I have an Ubuntu 14.04.3 (with linux-generic-lts-vivid (3.19) kernel) 64-bit host, and a VirtualBox guest with the same OS and configuration.

The host has an AMD A10-7800 CPU.

If I enable the KVM paravirtualization interface in VirtualBox, do I need to change anything in the guest in order to take advantage of it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [Virtualbox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#gimproviders):

> Most mainstream, modern operating systems, including Windows and
>   Linux, ship with support for one or more paravirtualization
>   interfaces. Hence, there is typically no need to install additional
>   software in the guest (including VirtualBox Guest Additions) to make
>   use of this feature.
>
> VirtualBox provides the following interfaces:
>
> - **Minimal:** Announces the presence of a virtualized environment. Additionally, reports the TSC and APIC frequency to the guest
>     operating system. This provider is mandatory for running any Mac OS X
>     guests.
> - **KVM:** Presents a Linux KVM hypervisor interface which is recognized by Linux kernels starting with version 2.6.25. VirtualBox's
>     implementation currently supports paravirtualized clocks and SMP
>     spinlocks. This provider is recommended for Linux guests.
> - **Hyper-V:** Presents a Microsoft Hyper-V hypervisor interface which is recognized by Windows 7 and newer operating systems.
>     VirtualBox's implementation currently supports paravirtualized clocks,
>     APIC frequency reporting, guest crash reporting and relaxed timer
>     checks. This provider is recommended for Windows guests.

Ubuntu kernels are compiled with KVM guest support, as you can see in the output of `grep CONFIG_KVM_GUEST /boot/config-*`, so there's no need to change anything in the guest system.

I think you should install Guest Additions. I didn't run any benchmark but I felt the guest system more fluid and responsive with Guest Additions & KVM when compared to KVM alone. Also, without Guest Additions you won't be able to access shared folders or copy/paste between host and guest.